# Hide text on hover and show an image

Tags: html, css, hover, hide, show

I made a button with some text in it and I want the text to disappear on hover and an image to appear in its place. Here is the HTML code:

```css
#facebook {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
#facebook:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: rgba(59, 89, 152, .6);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">
  <div id="facebook"><span id="text">Facebook</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

So basically I want a Facebook logo to appear instead of text. I tried to do it alone, but I failed. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you don't use a `div` inside an `a` . it could cause errors. so i changed a bit your html structure ( the solution works the same with your html structure ) .

so i set the `id` `#facebook` directly on the `a` and if you want it to behave like a `div` just add `display:block` to `a#facebook`

second, i've hidden the text when hover with `visibility:hidden`, you can also use `opacity:0` . in this case it won't matter.

> ***keep*** in mind that  you can use `transition` with `opacity` but not with `visibility`

then on `:hover` added a `background-image` to the `#facebook` element ( you can add whatever url you like )

let me know if it helps ;)

```css
#facebook { 
width: 200px; 
height: 50px; 
border-style: solid; 
border-color: white;
border-width: 1px;
border-radius: 7px;
line-height: 50px;
display: table-cell;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s;

transition: all 0.5s;
background-position:center center;
}

#facebook:hover{ 
width: 200px; 
height: 50px; 
border-style: solid; 
border-color: white;
line-height: 50px;
background-color: rgba(59, 89, 152, .6);
background-image:url("http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico");
background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
#facebook:hover #text {
  visibility:hidden;
 
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com" id="facebook"><span id="text">Facebook</span></a>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great, only the image isn't centered.

Comment: that's a very easy fix . just add `background-position:center center` to `#facebook` ; you can also add `text-align:center` if you want //// edited my answer

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much for helping me and explaining your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that?

https://jsfiddle.net/d04pLr6q/

```
#facebook { 
width: 200px; 
height: 50px; 
border-style: solid; 
border-color: white;
border-width: 1px;
border-radius: 7px;
line-height: 50px;
display: table-cell;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s;
transition: all 0.5s;
background-color: rgba(59, 89, 152, 1);
overflow:hidden;
text-align: center;
color:white;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
}
#facebook:hover{ 
width: 200px; 
height: 50px; 
border-style: solid; 
border-color: white;
line-height: 50px;
background-image: url(http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/facebook_2015_logo_detail.png);
background-size: 100%;
background-position: center;
color: transparent;
}
```

You can replace this facebook img with any logo. Its not perfect but pure CSS :)

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 blocks of hover CSS. See example below and adjust as needed.

```css
#facebook { 
width: 200px!important; 
height: 50px!important; 
border-style: solid; 
border-color: white;
border-width: 1px;
border-radius: 7px;
line-height: 50px;
display: table-cell;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s;
transition: all 0.5s;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;

}


img {
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    display: none;
  
}

#facebook:hover img { 
display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;

}

#facebook:hover #text { 
display: none;
}

#facebook img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">

<div id="facebook">

<span id="text">Facebook</span>

<img src ="http://i65.tinypic.com/2evxmqs.jpg" width="150px" height="45px" />

</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#facebook {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
#facebook:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: rgba(59, 89, 152, .6);
}
#facebook span {
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
#facebook:hover span {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">
  <div id="facebook"><span id="text">Facebook</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: But where do I add the logo image? This just hides the text.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JavaScript for that.

```
document.getElementById('facebook').onmouseover = function(){
    document.getElementById('facebook').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('facebook').style.backgroundImage = 'url(pic.jpg)';
    document.getElementById('facebook').style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
};
document.getElementById('facebook').onmouseout = function(){
    document.getElementById('facebook').innerHTML = 'Facebook';
    document.getElementById('facebook').style.backgroundImage = 'none';
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I want to do it with CSS only if possible.

Comment: why use javascript for a simple task that can be done easily with just CSS ?